# Consuming wcf webservice in Webmatrix with razor?

Tags: wcf, web-services, webmatrix

I've searched around and I can't find anything that shows how to consume a WCF webservice with Webmatrix using razor? I don't want to consume it with jQuery, I want to actually use the C#/razor syntax for that. Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something along the lines of "Add Service Reference" from Visual Studio, it isn't available in Web Matrix. You'll need to write all the plumbing by hand or use one of the Visual Studio Express products (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).